# how to pass $rootscope which is an object includeing 10s of parameter to state in UI-Router of Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

Hello I am a new developer, I have this problem passing a root-scope parameter to my state using UI-Router.

Here is my href which i want to change it to ui-sref :

```
href="/mycarts/{{cats.id}}?{{$root.filterParams}}
```

Here is my state:

```
.state('mycarts', {
    url : '/mycarts/:id?vendors&' +
          'price_to&price_from&manufacturer&' +
          'editor&theme&page&order&filter_by&no',
    templateUrl : 'partials/mycarts.html',
    controller : 'MyCartsController'
```

And this is how i passed parameter to controller:

```
    $scope.id = $stateParams.id;
```

so basically everything for id parameter works fine but i need to pass other string query as well which are a lot  , I don't know how to pass other string query to it what is the correct way of changing my href above to ui-sref.

Comment: `ui-sref="mycarts({id: cats.id, vendors: $root.filterParams.vendors})`

Comment: @Phil : In fact $root.filterParams contains all of the query string value in object. in fact should o pass all of the string parameter as well?? like : `ui-sref="mycarts({id: cats.id, vendors: $root.filterParams.vendors, price_to: $root.filterParams.price_to, price_from: $root.filterParams.price_from, AND THE REST})`  ..... is it the clean way?

Comment: You can but only the parameters defined in your state config will be available via `$stateParams`

Comment: Also, I wouldn't put line breaks in the `url` property

Comment: @Phil .. yes i know how to define it in state ... to tell you the truth there were like 10 string parameter i should pass which made me thinking is this the clean way of it.... so ... thank you :)

Comment: @Phil yes ... yes i didn't as well just wanted to make it readable in stackoverflow

Comment: the entire premise of this question is confusing.  the *whole point* of using `$rootScope` is to store parameters that are visible to all `$scope` objects created after the variable, which would imply that you don't need to pass `$rootScope` parameters around in your app at all.  However, using `$rootScope` in this way is an error prone anti-pattern, and the *recommended* way to store properties for multiple controllers is a service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create an object for use in `ui-sref` in your controller like so

```
$scope.linkParams = angular.extend({id: $scope.cats.id}, $scope.$root.filterParams);
```

(see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend)

Then use it in `ui-sref`

```
ui-sref="mycart(linkParams)"
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is not really required to use href, write a function in the controller and invoke it as onclick of your button or link.

**HTML**

```
<a style="text-decoration: underline" href="" ng-click="gotToMycarts()">Go</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
.controller('TestController',function($state){
   $state.transitionTo('mycarts',{id :12,vendors:'Test',price_to:200});
}).controller('MyCartsController',function($state, $stateParams){
  console.log($stateParams.id);
  console.log($stateParams.price_to)
})
```